# Extending Modules in Cucumber

Tags: ruby, module, cucumber, capybara

I know that in Cucumber that I can create a module and then include that module into the `World` object and all the methods that I have created within the newly created module are available globally

```
module MyModule
  def my_method

 end
end
World(MyModule)
```

Now anywhere in my cucumber tests I can call `my_method` and it will work

The issue I see here and an issue I have come across is duplication of method names, as the application gets bigger or other testers/developers work on the application.

So if I was to wrap everything up in its own module and create `module methods` like so

```
module MyModule
  def self.my_method
    page.find('#element')
 end
end
World(MyModule)

MyModule.my_method
# This will return undefined variable or method 'page' for MyModule module
```

So being new to using modules I have read that you can `extend` other modules so that you can use those methods within another module

So to access the `page` method I would need to access `Capybara::DSL`

```
 module MyModule
 extend Capybara::DSL
  def self.my_method
    page.find('#element')
 end
end
World(MyModule)
```

`MyModule.my_method` now works, but my question is rather than extend individual namespaces for every module that I need access to is there a way to extend/include everything or is this a bad practice?

Another example of where things fail are when I try to access instances of a class

```
module SiteCss
 def login_page
   Login.new
 end
end

class Login < SitePrism::Page
 element :username, "#username"
end

module MyModule
 extend Capybara::DSL
  def self.my_method
    page.find('#element')
   login_page.username.set('username')
 end
end
World(MyModule)
```

So with this example if I was it try and call `login_page.username` I would get

```
undefined method `login_page`
```

I'm really looking for the correct way to be doing this.

In conclusion I am trying to understand how to use custom modules and classes in cucumber without having to load everything into the World object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's not pretty to extend a module multiple times, if that's really what you want to do, I can suggest a way you can improve it a bit:

base class which will inherit your page object framework and extend(include is probably the correct option here):

```
module Pages
  class BasePage < SitePrism::Page
    extend Capybara::DSL
  end
end
```

Now your login class:

```
module Pages
  class Login < BasePage
    element :username, "#username"

    def yourmethod
      page.find('#element')
      username.set('username')
    end
  end
end
```

Now the bits you are probably interested in, expose yourmethod to cucumber world:

```
module SiteCss
  def page_object
    @page_object ||= Pages::Login.new
  end
end

World(SiteCss)
```

Now you should have access to yourmethod in a cleaner way...

Usage:

```
@page_object.yourmethod
```

Although the most important suggestion I could give you is run from SitePrism... Create your own page object framework... don't fall into SitePrism trap...